# establishing a Github ssh connection - is this the right way

Tags: git, github, msysgit

I was following the [help.github.com/win-set-up-git/](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) process and kept getting the `Host key verification failed` message with no clues when testing the ssh link. I'm working on Windows XP, with msysgit from the recent Git version Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.

I didn't find the Github support pages that helpful (not having used unix in anger in 30 yrs), so after a good bit of googling I got to this. I'd welcome comments and suggestions to make it better.

I found various refs to [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html), for "pinging" the port. I downloaded the windows version and used `nmap -p 22 github.com` (from a DOS window) to establish I didn't have a firewall or router issue.

When generating your ssh key you must change the unix file permission of your private key file with `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*` - it's ignored if it doesn't have those permissions!

The main trick I discovered was adding an option in the `ssh` test line `ssh -vT -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" git@github.com`. This resolves a windows/tty issue with the github key storage prompts.

While this worked for me, have I introduced any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need those ssh options, and `Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002` isn't recent.

Try it with the latest [PortableGit-1.7.6-preview20110709.7z](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list): unzip and add the bin directory to your PATH.

The key for those MinGW-based product to work is to define an environment variable called `HOME`, which isn't defined by default on Windows.
You can set that `HOME` to whatever directory you want (`C:\Users\Me` is usually a good choice), and then you will open a bash Git session in which you will execute the ssh commands.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at the newer version and see how it handles my scenario. I've sent some notes [I cloned help.github] to Github as well.

Comment: what is the difference between the 'portable' version, and the (smaller) regular .exe version

Comment: @Philip: the portable version is easier to install: just uncompress and add the bin directory to the `PATH`. You can have that way several version of msysgit without problem.